# How to write an API for a .Net application - unable to access config file

Tags: c#, .net

I am writing an API for an existing .Net application, in order to use that application as an 'engine' for other custom applications (that may be written by customers). The premise is that the 'engine' will always be installed and working on the target machine.

My approach is to create a new project in the VS solution for the 'engine' application, a class library that provides public methods to aggregate the fine-grained functionality of the application's own  libraries into higher level, simplified method calls for a 3rd party application author to use.

The API works well in the context of the 'engine' solution, unit tests working correctly. However, when I attempt to author a simple 'custom' application outside that VS solution, using a reference to the API to provide the services I need, I hit a problem - unless my custom aplication has a copy of the "engine"'s *app.config* (sic) file before it is compiled, the engine throws an exception when it attempts to access its config file.

It clearly is impractical to expect the 3rd party developer to have the app.config file to hand, and  a bit inelegant to expect them to have to copy the engine's config file into their solution and and rename it.

Is there a cleaner way to do this? The aim is for the custom application to need a reference to the API assembly only, and for the engine to 'just work' as if it were being used normally. Preferably binary remoting, web services and COM are to be avoided (assuming they will solve the problem).

Oh, this is all .Net 3.5 & VS2008
TIA

Comment: My first thought is: try to keep the engine as clean as possible, so avoid any config file for the engine. All configurations parameters must be passed by the 3rd party developer through an API that set the "environment" of the engine. So your Engine will behave like a black box.

Comment: Impossible - the 'engine' is an established application and is a given, and has a complex config file. Can't change that. The app developer is not supposed to know what the engine needs in order to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, use NuGet.
If you package your assembly in a NuGet package you can add a [configuration file transform](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/creating-packages/configuration-file-and-source-code-transformations) that will automatically add/update your engine's configuration properties.  Then, when your consumers pull your reference (from local NuGet server?), then they will get the assembly reference and the config transform.

I would recommend to make a formal configuration section for your engine so that you know that you are only managing its configuration in the NuGet package.

Comment: What's the official strategy for writing an API for a .Net application?

Comment: I don't work for Microsoft so I don't know the "official" strategy :), but...It depends.  If you are deploying the API as a library (assembly) that you want developers to reference, then I would say that NuGet is becoming the best practice.

Comment: In the past, binaries were usually downloaded and then referenced from a lib file at t he solution root.  Any configuration that the assembly required was then added by hand by the consuming developer.  This configuration was usually specified in the API docs.

Comment: That's a shame - it means that the app developer is ging to have to have a copy of the engine's config file at code time, and add anything locally needed to that file. It also means that if the engine is upgraded and its config file is changed, the external app will need to be recompiled with the new config file, even if the functionality it uses hasn't changed. Incidentally I've found that a ,Net app cannot use a COM interop reference to another .Net app (ie the engine) that is registered for COM. I wonder why this is prohibited?

Comment: What I find odd is that apparently I can expose and register the engine API for COM, write a 3rd party app in a non-.Net language that accesses the engine API via COM (no config file issues here, presumably, because the non.Net app wouldn't understand config files) but I can't do the same (or same effect) when writing a .Net client app. How strange is that?